# connect mysql docker container to outside application

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, docker, network-programming

I am attempting to connect a MySQL database server being run on a Docker container to a conversation.one chatbot I have been developing. The Docker container is on a raspberry pi with hypriot installed. Currently on the conversation. one app I have

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
var db = {
    host: "???",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "TimeTracker"
};
var pool = mysql.createPool(db);

  function ConnectToMysql(context, req, res) {

    console.log("==> ConnectToMysql");
    var query = "SELECT * FROM BTSTT";
    return pool.query(query, [])
        .then(function(rows) {
            console.log("== ConnectToMysql rows:%o",rows);
            if (rows.length) {
                var row = rows[0];
                return res.say(row);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("<== ConnectToMysql catch:"+err.message);
            return false;
        });
}
```

I have opened up the port for the portainer container so it can be accessed remotely at ulimi.ddns.net.
The MySQL container then has an IP address of 172.17.x.x. If I currently try to run my script with either
the IP of my raspberry pi, 192.168.x.x or the IP of the MySQL container, I get a timeout error.

A couple things:
1. I have been advised to run the MySQL database on a container and then store the information on an external hard drive. I have not yet set up the latter part of this, but if there is a better idea on how to do this I'd love to hear.
2. I need all of this to be set up so I can access it remotely from a different network then where it is being hosted. Eventually I plan on switching the server to a cloud platform, but for now I need it set up to have the same abilities.

Comment: can you share how you've created that mysql container on your raspberry pi, i.e. the Dockerfile you're using and/or the full `docker run ...` command. I suspect you need to expose the container port on the host, i.e. `docker run [image] -p [host port]:[container port]`.

Comment: @StefanR thanks for replying. The command I used was: docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d hypriot/rpi-mysql:latest. And the portainer command I used was: docker run -d -p 80:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer